# Filtering a subtree from an XML

Tags: c++, c, xml, libxml2, xml-libxml

There is an API xmlTextReaderPreservePattern() to filter all nodes matched by pattern (say "test"). Is there a way to filter a sub-tree from XML?

Comment: See the http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#reader3.c example.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this example, but in my case I need to filter out a subtree like:  <root><child><data></child><child1>data</child1></root> if this is the XML I should be able to filter out with subtree: <root><child1>data</child1> should match the XML and produce the output if exists.